# OpenSSL relocation error

Tags: openssl

I compiled libssl.so and libcrypto.so using openssl1.1.1d using `./config -d enable-ssl-trace`

When I use libssl.so and libcrypto.so and run my apps, it shows me this relocation error:

```
relocation error: symbol SSL_trace version OPENSSL_1_1_0 not defined in file libssl.so.1.1 with link time reference
```

I checked libssl.map and found SSL_trace is it OPENSSL_1_1_0 global feature.

How can I make it defined in file libssl.so.1.1?

Comment: how are you linking your compiled library on your program? in other words, are you sure you are linking the correct .so?

Comment: This is a programming question about dynamic linking, post it on stackoverflow

Answer (score 8):

Try to run this command:

```
$ sudo ldconfig
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have installed something like in below link:

https://cloudwafer.com/blog/installing-openssl-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04/

Try exporting as below or the path where you can find libcrypto.so.1.1, if it works then add it to ~/.bashrc

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/ssl/lib/
```